# Editing Pre Existing Spritesheet on Texture Packer - iOS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, texturepacker

I purchased some source code and I'm trying to re skin the app, however the app uses a sprite sheet generated from Texture Packer, and I'm having trouble replacing the images. I've even tried using the name file name and size but having no luck.

Could someone tell me how to do this please?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by having problems?  What's your code look like?  What kind of issues are you having?

Comment: The code isn't the issue. Basically the project came with existing graphics, so there is a helicopter which needs replacing, I have made my own helicopter in photoshop. However the existing helicopter is currently in the sprite sheet, so i need to replace my new helicopter with the old one.

Comment: I know of no automatic way to edit an existing spritesheet without the individual image files.  TexturePacker creates a final image, so you'll probably have to edit the helicopter in by hand using photoshop/illustrator.  Then you'll need to edit the plist file that defines the coordinates for each of the images in the sprite sheet.

Comment: Ask the author to provide the original TexturePacker .tps project files so you can edit the atlases. They ought to be part of the source code package.